How to limit testing-library `within` to only first-generation children?
I have a two-level nested list structure as follows:
<ul data-testid="parentList">
  <li>First parent
     <ul>
       <li>Child of first parent</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Second parent
    <ul>
      <li>Child of second parent</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

I want to assert that the parent list has 2 elements.
I've tried
const list = screen.getByTestId('parentList');
const listItems = within(list).getAllByRole('listitem');
expect(list).toHaveLength(2);

but since within(list).getAllByRole('listitem') also counts elements of child lists, the assertion fails:

Expected length: 2
Received length: 4

Is there any way I can limit the within query to count only top-level list items?

There does not seem to be a way to do this within testing-library, but the list of listitems can be limited to first-level items by filtering by parentNode:
const list = screen.getByTestId('parentList');
const listItems = within(list).getAllByRole('listitem').filter((listItem) => listItem.parentNode === list);
expect(list).toHaveLength(2);

